# Get Cell Data out of GridView with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET GridView server control.

I want a image button server control.

When a user is clicking on this image, a jQuery/JavaScript method should extract a value from a certain column in the row, where the click event was started.

```
<tr>
  <td>Col1</td>
  <td>Col2</td> <!-- Perhaps I want this Cell value -->
  <td>Col3</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried something like this:
function:

```
function readCellValue() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(#2)").val();//I get the error message undefined
    return false;//avoid a reloading process of my site

}
```

Grid View:

```
     <asp:GridView>
             <Columns>   
                <asp:BoundField ... />
                <asp:BoundField ... />
                <asp:BoundField ... />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtn"runat="server" OnClientClick="return readCellValue();"/>             
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit? What is happening or not happening?

Comment: Look where the attribute quotes are in your ImageButton (outside the self-closing element end). Fix that. Then notice that your `readCellValue` function doesn't return a value, or do anything else that might be useful.